# Sobrepor uma imagem sobre a outra com href="#imagem"

Tags: javascript, html, css, div

[image: Quero usar as ABAS da imagem como href e uma sobrepor a outra por cima]

Bom, exemplo melhor que isso do que eu quero fazer acho que não tem né ?
quero usar as aba da imagem como um link, quando a pessoa clica na aba "Loguin"
vai aparece a outra imagem por cima , vai esconder os input "text" (que no caso do registrar seria Email e Senha e um botao submit [OK]) dai depois de esconder os input e mudar a imagem, vai aparece o input "text" do Loguin (Usuario Senha e o botao submit) no mesmo espaço ocupado ...

deu pra entender né ? é 2 imagem com input e submit, só que quando clica nas aba eles mudam e ocupam o mesmo espaço.... é isso...

---

Edit : bom meu problema ainda continua haha, agora quando eu clico na tab a segunda imagem aparece em baixo, como o exemplo abaixo

https://ghostbin.com/paste/w7ysq

EXemplo do codigo, adicionei os link js, coloquei o script dentro do head do html , mas ainda não fez o que eu quero exatamente... quero fazer um Menu Mobile, a pessoa vai clica em um icone no canto superior esquerdo da tela e vai aparece essa div dai eu quero que as abas sejam alternadas com o clique onde ta escrito Loguin(entrar) e Registrar(cadastro) eu usei o map pra marcar o local dos clique já, só que não alterna, quando eu clico no Loguin aparece a segunda imagem abaixo

[image: quero uma imagem alternando entre uma e outra[2]]

Comment: Isso pode ser feito via JS. A tag PHP é desnecessária. A resposta também depende de você estar usando um framework como jQuery ou não. Esta página mostra como fazer isso em JS apenas: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp Obs. Você pode traduzir LOGIN como autenticação, entrar, acesso, etc, mas LOGUIN não dá!

Comment: pior... kkkk vo mudar loguin Entrar , vou da uma lida no link, se eu conseguir posto aqui embaixo o exemplo do JS e html

Comment: Ele usa o <button>name</button>
eu quero uma Href="#Entrar" e um para Href="#Registrar" usando <map> com as minhass coordenadas que vai fica bem em cima do Entrar/Registrar</map>  esse exemplo que vc mando, é como fazer um menu e carregar div dinamicamente, e pra fazer com imagem usando MAP e HREF ?? mesma coisa ? eu não tenho curso com HTML e CSS nem JS , tudo que eu sei eu aprendo na Net msm :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso, a forma mais fácil é usar uma biblioteca externa como jQuery.
O link a seguir te mostra a página do jQuery especifica para a criação de `tabs`: 
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Note como o código javascript é simples usando a biblioteca.

Comment: ajudo a eu entender , o problema que eu vo usa tabs de imagem, com link mapeado <map> um é menu de acesso mobile que eu quero fazer(vai ter um icone, dai a pessoa clica no icone e aparece uma div feita com css e tal bonitinha do tamanho da imagem qe eu usei de exemplo , porem quando eu clico pra ver a segunda imagem, ela aparece embaixo, eu quero que as 2 alternem no mesmo espaço, uma da tipo show, e a outra hide , só que nao sei fazer isso em javascript, sou leigo em js

Comment: Só que aí é outra parada. Não leve a mal, mas não é isso que você perguntou, lá em cima. Da forma que entendo este site, não é um fórum com discussões intermináveis que sabemos onde começam mas não onde vão terminar e os assuntos vão mudando. É muito importante manter o foco e objetividade. Se  respondi sua pergunta original, você deve aceitá-la (como já o fez) e com as dúvidas que surgiram, você faz uma nova pergunta, inclusive usando o código. Desta forma, não só você mas toda a comunidade vai sendo ajudada. Talvez, pegar a parte que iniciou com EDIT: e criar a nova a partir dali.